# Show explicitly the rank-24 Leech lattice that is also symmetric unimodular matrix with integer entries?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, lie-algebras, integer-lattices, packing-problem

A typical $E_8$ lattice is of the form of $E_8$ Cartan matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 &−1 &0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
−1& 2 &−1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& −1& 2& −1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& −1& 2& −1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& −1& 2& −1& 0& −1\\
0& 0& 0& 0& −1& 2& −1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& −1& 2& 0\\ 
0& 0& 0& 0& −1& 0& 0& 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Which $E_8$ Cartan matrix has all integer entries and with determinant $=1$.

This is a symmetric unimodular matrix.

### Question

Can you provide an explicit form of

- the rank-24 Leech lattice that is also symmetric unimodular matrix with integer entries?

What does it look like?

Note that the Leech generating matrix in Wikipedia is NOT symmetric and NOT unimodular, thus fails my criteria.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice#Constructions

Similar p.3 of this note shows NOT symmetric and NOT unimodular matrix:  [http://math.ups.edu/~bryans/Current/Journal_Spring_2006/ARoberts_LeechLattice.pdf](http://math.ups.edu/%7Ebryans/Current/Journal_Spring_2006/ARoberts_LeechLattice.pdf)

Comment: Note that the Cartan matrix of $E_8$ is not the generating matrix of the $E_8$ Lattice but the record of the inner products of the generating elements (aka the Gram matrix). The matrix on Wikipedia you mention is the matrix of generating elements. It is in fact unimodular (note the factor of $\sqrt{8}$) just not integral. If you compute the Gram matrix in this case it will be symmetric and should be integral and unimodular which is what you need

Comment: I feel like this point is made explicitly in the comments to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4815272/rank-24-leech-matrix-cannot-have-simultaneous-integer-entries-with-unit-determin)