# Rank-24 Leech matrix cannot have simultaneous integer entries with unit determinant or integer determinant?

Tags: number-theory, lie-algebras, quadratic-forms

A typical $E_8$ lattice is of the form of $E_8$ Cartan matrix:

```
    −1 2 −1 0 0 0 0 0
    
    0 −1 2 −1 0 0 0 0
    
    0 0 −1 2 −1 0 0 0
    
    0 0 0 −1 2 −1 0 −1 
    
    0 0 0 0 −1 2 −1 0
    
    0 0 0 0 0 − 1 2 0 
    
    0 0 0 0 −1 0 0 2
```

Which $E_8$ Cartan matrix has all integer entries and with determinant $=1$.

I find an expression of typical Leech lattice with all integer entries, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice#Using_the_binary_Golay_code

$$
8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
2 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
2 0 2 0 2 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0\\
2 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0\\
2 2 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0\\
0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0\\
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0\\
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0\\
-3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
$$
But this matrix has determinant $68719476736=2^{36}$.

In order to have the rank-24 matrix has determinant $1$, we need to multiply it by
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}.$$

- My question is that:

> Why the $E_8$ matrix can have simultaneous integer entries with unit determinant. But that the Leech matrix cannot have simultaneous integer entries with unit determinant or integer determinant? regardless whatever overall scalings - what this negative statement imply for Leech matrix, in contrast with the $E_8$ matrix?

Comment: While the expression you give is a Gram matrix for a scaling of the Leech lattice, there are Gram matrices for the Leech lattice with integer entries and determinant 1. (See for example [the 2nd Leech lattice entry in Nebe and Sloane's catalog of lattices](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/Leech.b.html).)

Comment: You are essentially asking about integral [unimodular lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_lattice), and the Leech lattice *is* an integral (even!) unimodular lattice, contrary to what you seem to think. Classical references such as Conway & Sloane's book on sphere packings should tell you more.

Comment: I like Ebeling, Lattices and Codes.  Briefer and more readable than SPLAG

Comment: Thanks "Leech lattice with integer entries and determinant 1. (See for example the 2nd Leech lattice entry in Nebe and Sloane's catalog of lattices.)" 
@Jeremy Rouse
  Do you mean the immediate matrix below GROUP_GENERATORS ??http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/Leech.b.html

Comment: @Will Jagy, I don't get the rank-24 matrix explicitly from a book. Can you point out which equation should I look at  Ebeling's Lattices and Codes???

Comment: The matrix you're giving is not a Gram matrix---it's not symmetric. This is the matrix that (appropriately rescaled) gives you an embedding in an Euclidean lattice. $E_8$ does not have such an integral matrix either.

Comment: Can any of you provide the rank-24 Leech matrix that is symmetric integral unimodular lattices? Just write this as an answer, then we can settle this once and for all... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let me call $L$ the Leech lattice and $A$ the matrix you've given. $\frac1{\sqrt8}A$ is the matrix that gives you an embedding of $L$ into $\mathbb{R}^{24}$ (with the standard scalar product).

Therefore, the Gram matrix associated to this embedding is $\frac18AA^t$, which is:
$$
\tiny
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 8 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3\\
 4 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
 4 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\
 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1\\
 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & -1\\
 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1\\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 2\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 2\\
-3 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &-1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 4
\end{array}
\right).
$$